# Using Razor query within x-kendo-template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a conditional Razor query to  determine whether or not to include an additional row in a kendo template. The value i am querying is part of the template. The question is how to use the kendo template variables within the razor code?

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="StatusTip">
  <div class="tooltipcontent">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> some row </td>
            <td> #= SystemStatus # </td>
        </tr>.
         @if (SystemStatus == 1)
        {
        <tr>
            <td> Some row</td>
            <td> some row </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor syntax if not required. Hash tags can be used to enclose the script blocks.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="StatusTip">
 <div class="tooltipcontent">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td> some row </td>
        <td> #= SystemStatus # </td>
    </tr>.
     #if (SystemStatus == 1){#
    <tr>
        <td> Some row</td>
        <td> some row </td>
    </tr>
    #}#
</table>
```